# Using fancybox API methods

Tags: jquery, api, fancybox

I am using Fancybox for popups and have one that I need to resize (when it's open). I have found the following API method;

```
$.fancybox.update()
```

I'm a little unsure of how to implement this. Do I need to add this to my existing script thats controlling the popup behaviour:

```
$('#myPopUp').fancybox();
```

Or does this get added somewhere else (jquery.fancbox.js for example)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just call it when you need it, like any normal method.